# AddAttribute error

Tags: php, magento

I try to update my custom model adding two new attributes to my model.

I modified the **config.xml** file adding version *0.0.2* and I create a new php file on sql folder called **mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php**

The file is executed correctly but Magento generates a report error that contains a generic error that says "*error in file...*"

Below you can find my code:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("configurador/vista", "radiovertical",  array(
    "type"     => "dec",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "Radio Vertical",
    "input"    => "text",
    "class"    => "",
    "source"   => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,
    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));

$installer->addAttribute("configurador/vista", "radiohorizontal",  array(
    "type"     => "dec",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "Radio horizontal",
    "input"    => "text",
    "class"    => "",
    "source"   => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,
    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Can someone say me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your model EAV or flat?

Answer (score 0):

`"configurador/vista"` should probably be replaced with `'catalog_product'`. The first field of `addAttribute()` is the `entity_type_id`. All available values for this field can be found in the table eav_entity_type (you can use either the entity_type_id or entity_type_code)